# Website not working on all browsers

Tags: css, web, safari, cross-browser

I’m having issues with my center site content getting “kicked over” to the right and the body “kicked over” to the left in Safari.  I’m a PC user and am trying to make it load correctly on all browsers (or as many as possible).  I’m using Dreamweaver and when I preview it in *Firefox, IE & Safari* it looks good but after I upload to *GoDaddy* it doesn’t work on my PC version of *Safari.*

I’ve made adjustments to my `alignment/padding/margins` in *css* to my *body* & *wrapper* and it seemed to help but not solve the problem.

I did validate my site on [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org) and came out with tons of errors, but they seem to mainly with my *javascript* for the smooth scroll feature which is working just fine.  (I also got an error for my favicon which is ok too, so I don’t get it.)

I have tested my site with [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) and it looks good so is it just my version of Safari I am starting to wonder.

This is my 1st site and I’m mainly self-taught so any suggestions would be helpful. (My code could be better organized I am sure so apologies for that.)

[www.thesarahcreative.com](http://www.thesarahcreative.com)

Comment: Please add meaningful code here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: The PC version of Safari is no longer supported by Apple, nor is it available anywhere. There are a number of known bugs in it. Does this show up in Safari 6 (Mac only) If not, unless you think you have a big audience using Safari 5 for PC, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Thanks, Mike - that eases my mind.  I didn't want to throw it out to the world and have it all jacked up.  Thank you!

Comment: And thanks, Matt Ball!  I would have pasted a piece of code had I known where my problem was lying.